# Steering object by head VR Cardboard

Tags: c#, android, virtual-reality

Can somebody tell me how to do head based steering? I know how to do it while mooving only camera, but i want to moove object by head and camera to follow the object.
I need this because i want to implement game logic to the object(it will aleso work for me if i can treat camera as an normal object).

I found this code for steering only camera:

```
public float speed = /* some number */;

private CardboardHead head;

void Start()
{
head = // find the CardboardHead
// example:
// head = Camera.main.GetComponent<StereoController>().Head;
// or, make the variable public and use drag-and-drop in the Editor
}

void Update()
{
transform.position += speed * head.Gaze.direction;
}
```

I'm starting to make games for unity so if I made some mistakes please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using cardboard plugin for Unity from here?
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download

if you do, then there is a prefab called cardboard main, put it in the scene, then if you see there is a game object called `Head` inside it and it contains `CardboardHead` script. So here is in your script:

```
public GameObject head; // drag the Head gameobject to here or you can just get it from the start

void Start()
{
    if (!head) // if you didn't drag the gameobject
    {
        head = FindObjectOfType<CardboardHead>().gameObject;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    transform.position += speed * head.transform.forward; // it is better to multiply by Time.deltaTime
}
```

also btw why it is tagged as Java?

---

New questions:

[image: attachment]

So here is what I did. I split the 'visual' and 'mechanic'. I removed the Mesh Renderer from the player, freeze its rotation for the rigidbody. I made a new child for the 'visual' it has a Script called `Rotate.cs` and removed its collider.

Changes to script:
in `Forward.cs` use the `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed);` back, and in `Rotate.cs` just use

```
void Update () {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * 5);
}
```

That is the quickest solution I can think of, I'm sure there are other solutions which you can try

Comment: I added your script to my player object but it doesnt work as i supposed. It makes player be in the same place as cardboardhead but i can't steer it(it goes forward all the time). I understood something wrong? I can show you my code or printscreen if it will help.

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by steering? so do you want the object just stays in its position but when you move your head to the left, it will rotate facing left side with same position? Yeah that will be nice if I can see the code, I haven't really understood what do you want to achieve, so more clarifications will be great

Comment: I thought a bit about what I want to do and i think it's imposible.I wanted object to be steered like a car i racing game(camera is always on the back) but not by a keyboard but by cardboard camera position(the object would go forward all the time, would be turned only by cardboard camera). Is there any way it can be done this way or i have to try something else(i have one idea btw)?

Comment: I have done it but it works for me only if camera is inside object. If it is behind(i have script which holds it behind player) everything breakes.

Comment: That is certainly possible. there are lots of racing game in VR out there. The simplest you can do is, you put the car inside the camera, adjust the position and in that camera you just put `void Update() { transform.position += speed * transform.forward; }`. So this way the camera will act as the controller and because the `CardboardHead` script is also in there, in controls the rotation of itself and its children

Comment: I really dont get your idea. You say that I should add this code `void Update() { transform.position += speed * transform.forward; }`to cardboardhead script or separate script? And then make the car(or anything else) child of the camera? If you could paste some code to clarify this or explain a little bit more i would be very grateful. In my version it works different :/

Comment: Are you using cardboard plugin? Is there any object Called 'Head' with `CardboardHead` script in it? if it is there, you put a new script call it something like `MoveForward`.cs and then inside that you put `void Update() { transform.position += speed * transform.forward; }`. That code will move the object which is using the script to its forward Vector.   So at this point your Head object will move on its own to wherever direction it is facing. Then if you add your car as the child of the Head, it will just follow its parent. Do you get the idea?

Comment: OK i get it now :D I can't write it at the moment, but i will as soon as i have some free time. I have only one doubt: won't it cause the car to fly with the camera instead of driving on the road(in my other game I made smth similiar and it caused some bugs)? btw I'm using this google plugin

Comment: yeah that's true, what you can do is either put the camera into the ground (like using physics or character controller), the other way is you split the car and the camera as different object and like the answer post that I gave, you put script in the car to move forward based on the rotation of the Head object.

Comment: Ok i made what you said and it almost works. The problem is that the camera doesnt follws the object correctly(i added rigidbody to the object because it didnt work with camera). There are preentcreens of the problem: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz8CX_tJ7Ym_dWtTYjBDR1B5Rnc&usp=sharing btw it works quite fine until i move camera(but object aleso drops on the ground and camera remains on the same hight)

Comment: The main problem is that when I make script which rotates camera(object is rotated by cardboardhead script) it creates endless loop because both scripts track rotation based on the other object.

Comment: OK now i have got project in which camera is inside object(its not a child but it's inside) and object goes in the direction which camera is facing. I think this is enough for me, because i cant really make the object rotate same as camera. My only problem now is that when camera is facing up or down the object wants to go same direction. Is there any way to rotate object only on y axis?

Comment: so for your previous reply: If the camera does not have rigidbody but its children (which is the object) has rigid body it won't work really well. For the 2nd reply: you can do some modifications to the hierarchy structure so there will be parent and grand-parent objects which control rotation (e.g. parent receives control from mouse, then grand parent receives control from cardboard), it is a bit hard to explain hmm.

Comment: For your 3rd reply: So camera is attached to the GameObject? Yeah you can obviously lock the other rotation, check this script if this help to form the logic for you [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/29741/mouse-look-script.html). I'm not sure if I explain it properly, if there is something you don't understand just ask me, also it will be great you post the hierarchy of your current project?

Comment: I dont't understand linked script that you gave me(which part locks the rotation). Here is my current project hierarchy and video of how it works https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz8CX_tJ7Ym_WDNoeDlvZEhSbWs&usp=sharing . I'm really curious about what you wrote about grand-parent objects which control rotation. Can you say a little bit more about that? Can it work without mouse steering(because it won't work with mouse on smartphone)? btw i can add whole unity project to shared folder if you want.

Comment: Now I made project in which the object rotates like the camera without x axis(thats what i wanted). There is one problem: the object behaves weirdly when it goes on ramp or hits the wall. Is there any other way of making what I made but with object behaving normaly liek in normal 3d game(it bounces off the walls etc.). There is my project(its hard to explain everything): https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz8CX_tJ7Ym_aEF5LURGOF9ibVU&usp=sharing In this game you have to pick up green cubes.

Comment: I got your project. So if you want to the object uses physics here is what you do in `Forward.cs`, you should never use `transform.position` for physics, instead use `rb.AddForce(transform.forward * speed * 10); // times 10 because physics is a bit heavier`, so get the rigidbody of the gameobject (you can use drag in inspector or `rb = GetComponent<RigidBody>()` in `Start()`). And if you want the bounciness, in the project, right click and make new Physics Material, set the bounciness to 1, then put the physics material in the colliders of the wall and player sphere

Comment: Ok thanks for the script. It worked for me, now i have working phisics, but because the ball doesn't roll it's sliding on the ground. Is there na change that i could make to my project to make the ball roll(with phisics left)? My idea is to don't change the x rotation in `TrackCameraRot.cs`, then make the child object that is in center of the ball and tracks y and z rotation and sets x to 0. Then i can attach the camera to this child object. What do you think about this idea? If it is ok could you tell me how to change y and z rotation and leave x as it is?

Comment: Sorry don't quite understand what you mean, I cant open the project as for now. But if you want the ball to be rolling, if you want to do physics again just use `rb.AddTorque(transform.right * rotateSpeed)` in `Update()` to keep it rotating all the time. The ideal way to do this is by putting collider and rigidbody different from the mesh renderer (the ball mesh), so the one that involves in game mechanic (collider and rigidbody) is different from appearance (the mesh which just rotating). Btw, are you using this https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial?

Comment: This script which you gave me will cause the ball to rotate, but its not what i wanted to make. I want the ball to rotate because its touching the ground, not because the script is rotating it(i think it makes the difference, if not correct me). Second thing is that when i put this script in `Forward.cs` it does not affect the ball(probably because `TrackCameraRot.cs`). Is there any way to make this script   `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, head.transform.eulerAngles.y, head.transform.eulerAngles.z);` dont change the eulerAngle.x? If i know how to do it i can try my idea of making it.

Comment: btw Yes i'm using Roll a Ball project because i think it's quite good for testing

Comment: you can do `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, ...);`.

Comment: So you only want the ball to rotate if it is touching the ground, you can put condition for the `AddTorque`. For example, if there is character controller, there is `characterController.isGrounded` which check if it touches the ground. But since you are using rigidbody http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/196381/how-do-i-check-if-my-rigidbody-player-is-grounded.html that might help you. Or if you are lazy using raycast and since your character always stay in flat position just use `if transform.position.y < ? {AddTorque()};`

Comment: Ok i know where is the problem. When I added this script `rb.AddTorque(transform.right * rotateSpeed)` it madde ball rotate only 90 degrees and then it was facing the ground all time. It was like this because of `TrackCameraRot.cs`. This script sets y and z rot of ball to camera rotation. I have noticed that when ball is rolling forward the y and z rotations sometimes change to 180, and my `TrackCameraRot.cs` is blocking it and the ball is not rotating as it should. Do you have any idea how to fix it? Hopefully it will be final correction to my project :)

Comment: Sure: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0Bz8CX_tJ7Ym_ejlLdDBoOFI4Nmc&usp=sharing . It's in scene3.

Comment: Thanks for the code it works great, but thats not exactly what was my problem. I just wanted the ball to really rotate(like in Roll a Ball tutorial)  not just look to rotate(i dont really need that). The difference id that in your project the ball slide on the groun and steering is harder. I tried to do that, but none of my ideas worked :/ Do you have an y solution for this?

Comment: I think this is source of my problem(the ball is rotatin only 90 degrees in my previous project): http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/63971/unexpected-axis-values-when-a-sphere-rotates-360-d.html . I don't understand this quaternions, so i probably have to dont rotate the ball, but just add force to it and let it slide a bit on the ground.

Comment: Okay, so put everything as it was before (dont use my answer). Here is the problem, your `TrackCameraRot` is conflicted with `AddTorque`, so turn off your `TrackCameraRot` then in `Forward.cs` you add reference to the cardboard head and then do `rb.AddTorque(head.transform.right * rotateSpeed);`. Also you might want to constraint local rotation of the rigid body, see http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/404420/rigidbody-constraints-in-local-space.html

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate your help! Now it all works for me :) I have not constrainted local rotation of the rigidbody because I think I dont need it(everything works just fine). Can you tell me why I might want to use it?

Comment: it is just a safeguard so the ball will only roll, not rotating in pitch or yaw. Also you might wanna change to `FixedUpdate()` instead of `Update()` for physics